# How to get the Decibel values and frequency of an audio in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, frequency, decibel

i can play the audio using audioplayers package. but i can't able to get the decibel and frequency of an playing audio.

[image: audio play]

[image: audio play]

Answer (score 0):

@Vennila Murugesan Please check out the `flutter_audio_recorder` package, which allows you to record audio and provides access to audio data.